# Is it possible to find the location of another android phone?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I'm new to development for Android and I am curious if it is even possible to request and accurate location of another android device?  For example, If I wanted to find where a friend is located and show it on my device in google maps.

Answer (score 5):

It is also possible to do if you install an "app" on the device that you want to track that contains a Broadcast Receiver that is triggered by a specific event (i.e. - an SMS message with a certain "code" in the message).  you could then have the phone get its location (either Network or GPS, if possible) and return that value back to you.

Everything could happen in the background as long as the app is installed.  App does not need to be running.

Even though this is possible it crosses a LOT of gray lines :-)

Comment: Hi, can you suggest me some code to find the location on other device. I have idea about getting the Latitude & Longitude of my device. Help me

Answer (score 4):

This is possible, but the remote device has to be actively pushing its location somewhere. For example, you could open a socket connection to the remote device, and have it stream its location to you, or both devices could communicate with a central server. It is not possible to get the location of an arbitrary other device. (This would be a pretty clear security nightmare.)

Comment: Latitude API has been deprecated, and will be turned down on August 9, 2013.